# How to pulls related values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my problem.

I have two tables like user and customer. Users can be related to some customer(s).

For example, I have a user who relates to two customers, and the other user relates to three customers, etc.

This is my code that creating tables and inserting values;

```
create table tbl_user
(
 id int,
 username varchar(100),
 relatedcustom_id int
)

 create table tbl_custom
(
 id int,
 name varchar(100)
)

 insert into tbl_custom values(1,'john'),
 (2,'adam'),
 (3,'steve'),
 (4,'marliyn'),
 (5,'coco'),
 (6,'George');

 insert into tbl_user values (1,'cst_moose',1),
 (1,'cst_moose',2),
 (2,'cst_moose',3),
 (3,'cst_kevin',2),
 (4,'cst_kevin',5),
 (5,'cst_donald',1),
 (6,'cst_donald',2),
 (7,'cst_donald',4),
 (8,'cst_henry',1),
 (9,'cst_henry',6),
 (10,'cst_michel',1),
 (11,'cst_michel',2);
```

I want to pull the user name(s) that relates to customers that id is 1 and 2.

Here is my select code;

```
  select username from tbl_user where exists (select 1 from tbl_custom 
  where 
  id in(1,2))
  except
  select username from tbl_user where exists (select 1 from tbl_custom 
  where 
  id not in(1,2))
```

But this query demonstrates nothing.

The other select code ;

```
select username from tbl_user where relatedcustom_id in (1,2)
except
select username from tbl_user where relatedcustom_id not in (1,2)
```

This query shows like this;

```
  username
  --------
  cst_michel
```

What I want to do is a Select - As - From with the following fields

```
   username
  --------
  cst_michel
  cst_moose
  cst_donald
```

Comment: Your `EXISTS`'s need correlated sub-queries.

Comment: All your users have the same ID - `1`

Comment: I fixed the same ID problem @Svetlin Zarev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solution is to use arrays:

```
select username
from tbl_user
where relatedcustom_id in (1,2) -- to filter out unrelated data
group by username
having array[1,2] <@ array_agg(relatedcustom_id);
-- or '{1,2}' <@ array_agg(relatedcustom_id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working. `@`, why we use it, I don't understand. Can you explain it? @Abelisto

Comment: @MustafaBYKSY Look at the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html It is not `@` but `<@` operator

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pull the user name(s) that relates to customers that id is 1 and 2.

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select username
from tbl_user 
group by username
having sum( (relatedcustom_id = 1)::int ) > 0 and
       sum( (relatedcustom_id = 2)::int ) > 0 and
       sum( (relatedcustom_id not in (1, 2)::int ) ) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But, I need to send custom id fields as a list, I do not separate as shown above. Also, the query returns only `cst_michel`

Comment: @MustafaBYKSY . . . That is not the question you asked.

Comment: sorry, my English. @GordonLinoff